# SwiftUI: if Statement with modifiers

Tags: swift, if-statement, modifier

Is it possible to do something such as:

```
Vstack {
   Text("Hello, World!")
}
   if Role == "administrator" {
   .offset(y: 15)
}
```

Doing this right now gives an error on the `var body: some View {` line.

Comment: yes its totally posible

Comment: how is it possible since I can't figure it out.

Comment: see my answer and git it done :)

Comment: Try a ternary operator inside the modifier, `.offset(Role == "administrator" ? 15 : 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var Role: String = "administrator"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .offset(y: Role == "administrator" ? 15 : 0)
    }
}
```

[read more here](https://designcode.io/swiftui-handbook-conditional-modifier)